# which to use __call__, __setitem__ or custom function to set the angle of an instance of a joint class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a `Joint` class which controls the angle of the servo of the leg of a robot (instances of the `joint` class for example are `knee`, `hip`, or `ankle`). what would the best way do this? Here are my options, suppose I want to set the angle of the joint to 90 degrees

1. define a `set()` function so i can do `hip.set(90)`
2. override `__call___` function so i can do `hip(90)`
3. override `__setitem__` function so i can do `hip = 90`

What should I use? and why is this the best?

edit:

Right now my class looks like this:

```
class Joint:

    def __init__(self, joint_type, jkey, min_angle = -90, max_angle = 90):

        self.joint_type, self.name =  joint_type, jkey
        self.channel, self.min_pulse, self.max_pulse = joint_properties[jkey]
        self.min_angle, self.max_angle = min_angle, max_angle
        self.off()

    def set(self, angle):

        angle = constrain(angle, self.min_angle, self.max_angle)
        pulse = remap(angle, self.min_angle, self.max_angle, self.min_pulse, self.max_pulse)

        drive(self.channel, pulse)
        self.current_angle = angle

    def off(self):
        drive(self.channel, 0)
        self.current_angle = None
```

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, using a `set()` function is the clearest.

Comment: Or you could use properties, or a more explicit function name, or...

Comment: How about `set_angle()`? Or perhaps something like `move()`, if the function effectively moves the leg of the robot

Answer (score 3):

```
hip.angle = 90
```

But if you have validation, checking and side effects for that attribution (which probably you have), you can put a `property` in place for the `hip` attribute...

```
class Joint(object):
    ...
    @property
    def hip(self):
          return self._hip

    @hip.setter
    def hip(self, value):
          validate(value) 
          send_to_external_device(value)
          self._hip = value
```

This way to define getters and setters is a very nice feature of Python: to whoever makes use of instances of your class, all that is needed is an attribution. Under the hood, the getter and setter methods are called.

`property` is an special built-in decorator - in earlier versions, it only built the property object, and one had to pass in a normal function call the getter and optionally setter and deleter functions. The new decorator syntax is shorter, but looks a little magic -  the other way is easier to grasp what is going on for newcomers:

```
class Joint(object):
    ...

    def _get_hip(self):
          return self._hip

    def _set_hip(self, value):
          validate(value) 
          send_to_external_device(value)
          self._hip = value

    hip = property(_get_hip, _set_hip)
```

(this works just the same, but it also exposes the getter and setter functions in the class namespace)

Comment: +1. If there are side effect, I generally prefer to use methods rather than properties. But that's a matter of tastes.